# Kubernetes CNI Hairpin Traffic

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I setup a Kubernetes cluster using [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) tutorial, and the connection is hanging whenever a Pod connects to another Pod on the same node through a ClusterIP (hairpin traffic).

If I access the pods directly, without going through the ClusterIP, everything works fine.

So, visually, this doesn't work:

```
PodA -> ServiceA ClusterIP -> PodA 
PodA -> ServiceB ClusterIP -> PodB on same node
```

However, this works 100% great, as does any Pod contacting another Pod directly by it's IP:

```
PodA -> ServiceB ClusterIP -> PodB on other node
```

I found [Kubernetes Documentation about debugging services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) and went through it, and everything seems fine, up to the section [A Pod can't reach itself via Service VIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#a-pod-cannot-reach-itself-via-service-ip).

I see rules added for my services in `iptables-save` output (and I confirmed using `iptables` mode):

```
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/16 -d 10.32.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.32.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/16 -d 10.32.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.32.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
```

I can see from the kubelet's logs `promiscuous-bridge` hairpin mode flag:

```
kubelet[12496]: I1204 04:13:29.761707   12496 flags.go:33] FLAG: --hairpin-mode="promiscuous-bridge"
```

I don't see logs such as `Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge"` specifically confirming the mode, so I set it explicitly in the kubelet-config.yml also

Also, I edited the CNI plugin to add `promiscMode: true` ([docs](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/tree/master/plugins/main/bridge#network-configuration-reference)), and I see `PROMISC` on the `cnio0` interface:

```
cnio0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

At this point I think either 1) this tutorial doesn't have hairpin traffic working or 2) I screwed up something obscure that's breaking this, but I can't figure out what it is!

Since this Kubernetes the Hard Way tutorial is known to be the canonical setup reference, I'm doubting it would be #1... anyone have other suggestions to determine #2?

Comment: Could you please check if you got `"hairpinMode": true` in your CNI config?

Comment: @OhHiMark, you can only set one of `promiscMode` or `hairpinMode` to true in the CNI plugin. I set `promiscMode: true` since that seemed to correlate to the kubelet's `hairpinMode` setting of `promiscuous-bridge`. I assumed you'd use `hairpinMode: true` in the CNI plugin if you set kubelet `hairpinMode` value to `hairpin-veth` instead. I did however try both combinations and neither worked. I think you right, it must be something w/ CNI plugin.

Comment: Under [this Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45790) there is a discussion regarding this particular issue. Indeed the problem lays within the CNI and not Kubernetes itself. There is [another thread](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/issues/476) opened for that already.

Comment: Thanks! I saw those issues and figured it would've been resolved given how old they were, but maybe not. I'll look into the CNI situation. I think in another thread I found, someone used Cilium or another CNI plugin instead, and then hairpin traffic worked.

Comment: Good to hear that. I will post an answer so the rest of the community with a similar problem could also benefit from.

Comment: Did @Wytrzymały Wiktor answer help you to solve your problem?If yes,Please consider accepting and upvoting it.[What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with CNI documented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45790) and [here](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/issues/476).

> I think the abstract "allows hairpin behavior" is a property of
>   plugins. Some support it.  Some do not.  Some may support it in
>   multiple ways with configuration required.  If you don't support it in
>   a Kubernetes install, one class of Service behavior will not work
>   correctly.  That may be OK for some installations and not for others.

However, you can use [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) with `hairpinMode` set to `true` (the default flannel configuration does not set `HairpinMode` to `true`). That pat of the config would look like this:

```
    {
      "name": "<name_here>",
      "type": "flannel",
      "delegate": {
        "hairpinMode": true,
        "isDefaultGateway": true
      }
    }
```

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try it out soon and report back, I haven't had time to check it out.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try it out?

Comment: Still didn't try. Sadly, some work projects taking up time before end of the year. Will keep you posted on it ASAP